# Finding a lost question without enough rep

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

I'm pretty sure I've asked a question a while ago (years?) about the **use of ammonia in agriculture** where it is introduce directly into the soil. The question included a photo of a very large tank being drawn by a tractor in a field being treated.

I can't find it now though, and I wonder if it might have been automatically deleted for no activity.

If I had enough rep, I could type `user:16035 deleted:1` and see all of my deleted questions, but I don't, so I can't.

Is there any other way I can retrieve the text and links in the question, provided that I'm right and I did ask it here?

I'm trying to see if information or links from this question can also be helpful in my recent question [How can agricultural ammonia lead to PM2.5 production in the atmosphere?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/16627/6031)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if it's the *only* way, but since there are only three of them, it's quite little work for a moderator like me to find your deleted questions:

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/70534/need-a-basic-understanding-of-the-structure-of-water-and-kosmotropy

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/111161/what-gas-was-produced-in-orbit-from-33-pounds-of-benzoic-acid-and-anthraquinone

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/79019/are-all-these-molecular-diagrams-drawn-using-a-single-unified-system-where-can

As far as I can tell, none fit your description, so maybe try another site.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! You're right, it's not here. That's a puzzler for me, but there can't be too many more places it could be.

Answer (score 4):

I believe I found your lost question:https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/65163/why-do-soil-bacteria-produce-nitrous-oxide-as-a-result-of-anhydrous-ammonia-fert

Turns out you were looking in the wrong place, as you asked the question on Biology SE about a year and a half ago.

Comment: Thank you very much for your sleuthing assistance! This is surprising because after looking here I asked the same question in biology and a comment suggested that it wasn't asked there. [Finding a deleted question without enough rep](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3943/27918) Now I find that I'd never deleted the question to begin with. Feel free to post an answer there as, well!

Comment: @uhoh I just checked you profile for the sites where it could have relevant (here, Earth Science, Bio) and just searched the list of your questions for ammonia or agriculture

Comment: ...and luckily you either did not use the `deleted:1` qualifier that I mentioned, or you did and the (what I feel is strange) behavior that it returns non-deleted posts to users with reputation below a certain threshold. You have 7k+ here but much lower rep there. I think I will ask about this strange behavior in meta.

Comment: @uhoh I looked without any qualifiers, just what is publicly displayed on your site profiles.

Comment: just fyi (I now see you didn't use this kind of search): [Why does 'user:ID deleted:1 is:question' return undeleted results when reputation is insufficient for correct results?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326312/303080) Will you be posting an answer [here](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3943/27918) as well? If not, I'll answer it myself. Thanks!

Comment: @uhoh you can post over there, I don't have too much activity on Bio SE.